# How to handle time-based raster data in the ArcGIS Server JS API

Tags: raster, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, time, animation

The [TimeSlider](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi/timeslider.htm) functionality in the ArcGIS Server JS API is great for working with time-based vector features - you can scroll forwards and backwards through time to see the vector features which existed at a given time instant.

**Has anyone created a similar time-slider for rasters?**

I have a series of monthly weather grids which I'd like to display, allowing the user to scroll to any month (eg, show me the average rainfall for June).

The time-slider relies on the featureclass being defined in ArcMap with a Time attribute, but this isn't available for raster layers.

The best workaround I can think of is:

- create a separate map document for each raster
- build a separate tiled map service from each map document
- add a DOJO slider to the map, with increments to mark each raster
- use JavaScript to switch the appropriate raster on at each mark on the DOJO slider

Is anyone aware of a better/faster approach? This will be quite a laborious process as it will mean creating and maintaining multiple MXDs and MSDs.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The new [mosaic datasets](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/What_is_a_mosaic_dataset/009t00000037000000/) are [time-aware](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Time_in_a_mosaic_dataset/009t000001vs000000/) and can be published as [image services](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/About_serving_raster_and_image_data/009t000000p0000000/) (requires Image extension)

Esri has a [javascript sample](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jssamples/image_timeimageservice.html) , and if you look at the [image service details](http://servicesbeta.esri.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World/Aerial/ImageServer) you can see that there is a time extent along with the normal spatial extent, and even the [Query](http://servicesbeta.esri.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World/Aerial/ImageServer/query) operation supports time.

This is definitely a neater solution (provided you have access to the Image Extension), but under moderate load or large extents, I would speculate that switching between tiled services could be faster.

Comment: Genius, thanks for that. I haven't worked with Image services yet so I didn't realise they were time-aware. This should make things a lot easier